# How to set an android activity/fragment variables when app in backgroud?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-background

In USB camera supported android application.

I will make the app to go background when usb camera is connected.
when the app is in background, i will disconnect the camera from the device.
Next I will re-launch the app from background. After relaunch I would like to know that the camera got disconnected.

Is there any way to know in my activity or fragment when the camera got disconnected in background?

Answer (score 0):

For saving/recreating activity state read this:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

It also explains more about activity lifecycle.

Same can be achieved for fragments (lifecycle):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html